# Как сделать такой редирект в htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess

```
нужен универсальный редирект такого типа:
https://sitename.ru/glavnaya-amp/amp/ 
=> редирект на страницу (с гет параметром) 
https://sitename.ru/glavnaya-amp?amp
так же нужно чтобы редирект был без смены url
```

Comment: Вам нужно чтобы если пользователь кликнет по ссылке `https://sitename.ru/glavnaya-amp/amp/` он попадал в `https://sitename.ru/glavnaya-amp?amp` и при этом браузер не перезагружал страницу???

Comment: браузер перегружается, но урл не должен меняться

Comment: вообще не суть, про смену урл не главное, главное - нужен такой редирект

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте что-то вроде этого

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^amp=1$
RewriteRule ^/glavnaya-amp$ /glavnaya-amp/? [R=301,L]
```